# React - unique key in object gets overwritten when updating state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, reference, javascript-objects

I have a function that adds an item to a shopping cart. I'm trying to generate a unique key for a new object item when a button is clicked. I have `new Date().getTime()` doing this based on click frequency. I tested console.log's inside the function and it is generating different `unique_id` numbers for each new object. The problem starts when I try to combine the existing state array of objects with the new `item` object. All the existing `unique_id`s get overwritten to the latest `unique_id`. I'm also using React useState hook for the state array. React is somewhat relevant because the state array should not be edited directly but through the setter method.

I have tried a combination of `.push`, `.concat`, `Array.from`, spread operator, looping and assigning variables inside and outside the function. I know it's a `pass-by-reference` vs `pass-by-value` situation since those array methods are only shallow copies.

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

const addItem = (item) => {
   let cartArr = cart
   item['unique_id'] = new Date().getTime()
   setCart([...cartArr, item])
}
```

expected:

```
[
{id: 1, price: 10.11, title: "The Art Of War", unique_id: 1565675696123},
{id: 1, price: 10.11, title: "The Art Of War", unique_id: 1565675696256},
{id: 1, price: 10.11, title: "The Art Of War", unique_id: 1565675696377}
]
```

but got:

```
[
{id: 1, price: 10.11, title: "The Art Of War", unique_id: 1565675696377},
{id: 1, price: 10.11, title: "The Art Of War", unique_id: 1565675696377},
{id: 1, price: 10.11, title: "The Art Of War", unique_id: 1565675696377}
]
```

Comment: Can I know, where is `cartArr` variable defined?

Comment: i forgot to include to include the assignment: `let cartArr = cart`

Comment: Can you try to create a simple working React snippet reproducing this issue?

Comment: It depends on how frequently you are calling `addItem()`. Can you please log the time inside `addItem()` function to isolate the problem?

Comment: Do this which makes state's `cart` property immutable. `let cartArr = [...cart]`

Answer (score 2):

instead of pushing the value in the array you can concat the array and the object see the below code for your reference

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const addItem = item => {
    item["unique_id"] = new Date().getTime();
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };
```

here is the [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-jzdpb)

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comment, it depends on how frequently you are calling `addItem`.
The below snippet shows all items get the same time (almost always) if you call `addItem` consecutively:

```js
let cart = [];

const addItem = (item) => {
    let cartArr = cart;
    let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    item['unique_id'] = currentTime;
    cartArr.push(item);
    cart = cartArr;
}
addItem({ price: 10 });
addItem({ price: 11 });
addItem({ price: 12 });
console.log(cart);
```

However, after adding some delay by introducing `console.log` the timestamps are different (not guaranteed):

```js
let cart = [];

const addItem = (item) => {
    let cartArr = cart;
    let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Price: ' + item.price);
    console.log('Current time: ' + currentTime);
    item['unique_id'] = currentTime;
    cartArr.push(item);
    cart = cartArr;
}
addItem({ price: 10 });
addItem({ price: 11 });
addItem({ price: 12 });
console.log(cart);
```

So, here I think React state has nothing to do with the timestamp or array operations.

Answer (score 0):

As @fiveelements said, you are incurring in a clash of ids because `Date.now()` is not a solid way to generate random values. Luckily, browsers have a new functionality exactly for generating random values. You can try using this for your ids:

```js
const id = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(10))[0];
console.log(id);
```

You can read more about the [window.crypto object on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues). It's supported in all modern browsers, including IE11: https://caniuse.com/#search=crypto.

If you get that data from somewhere like a database, you probably already have some kind of unique id that you can use. If you can keep `key`s consistent across renders, it will improve performance by avoiding unnecessary re-renders. But if you don't have any id, this snippet can help you generate them on the fly.

You can also check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/giosensation/pen/NWKGegR).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with React. The executed loop happens to be completed within the same timestamp.

I would suggest not simulating adding multiple items in the cart via a looping.

```js
var arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  arr.push(new Date().getTime())
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have figured out till now, timestamp sucks for react as keys.

**IMPORTANT** - React expects **STABLE** keys, assignment of keys should be done once and every item should get same key every time, so that React can perform its magic for value changes and decide when to re-render.
But `new Date` function you will never give you STABLE key, always inconsistent. Every new value of function will give unique key.
Unique should be for a component in question and not globally for application, to avoid re-rendering for that component.

Always best to use some identifier like `id` from database.

If not available
I would advice to use `shortid` to generate keys.

Steps:-

1) `npm install shortid --save`

2) `import shortid from 'shortid';`

3) Usage

```
<li key={shortid.generate()}>
  {value}
</li>
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem with Object.assign(). It also doesn't need the extra `cartArr` variable.

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

const addItem = (item) => {
    item['unique_id'] = new Date().getTime()
    let newItem = Object.assign({}, item)
    setCart([...cart, newItem])
}
```